# AmPHP buffer keeps going forever

Tags: php, amphp

I've just picked up AmPHP and I'm trying to get the post body from my AmPHP http server, however, it keeps going forever (just never sends back a response to my client).
This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$resp = \Amp\Promise\wait($request->getBody()->buffer());
```

I've tested another piece of code that doesn't keep going forever but when I use that piece, I can't get my body outside the function in the `onResolve`:

```
$resp = $request->getBody()->buffer()->onResolve(function($error, $value) {
  return $value;
});
return $resp; // returns null
```

I've also tried this last bit but that also just returns `null`:

```
return yield $request->getBody()->buffer();
```

Edit: Done some more fiddling around, this is my current (still non-functional) code (although a lot has been stripped out for simplicity sake):

```
// Main loop
Loop::run(function() {
  $webhook = new Webhook();
  $resp = $webhook->execute($request);
  print_r($resp); // null
});

// Webhook
class Webhook {
  public function execute(\Amp\Http\Server\Request $request) {
    $postbody = yield $request->getBody()->buffer();
    return ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Webhook executed successfully', 'data' => $postbody];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: After the AMPHP v3 release [(changelog)](https://github.com/amphp/amp/releases/tag/v3.0.0) the code would look like this:

```
use Amp\Http\Server\Request;
use Amp\Loop;

class Webhook {
    public function execute(Request $request): \Amp\Promise {
        return new \Amp\Promise(function (callable $resolve) use ($request) {
            $postbody = yield $request->getBody()->buffer();

            $resolve([ 'success' => true, 'message' => 'Webhook executed successfully', 'data' => $postbody ]);
        });
    }
}

// Main loop
Loop::run(function () {
    $webhook = new Webhook();
    $resp = $webhook->execute($request);
    $output = yield $resp;
    print_r($output); // array with post body
});
```

Wrap execute method implementation to Amp\call() to return Promise instead of Generator. Then on the main loop yield the result to get the array instead of null.

```
// Webhook
class Webhook {
    public function execute( \Amp\Http\Server\Request $request ) {
        return Amp\call( function () use ( $request ) {
            $postbody = yield $request->getBody()->buffer();

            return [ 'success' => true, 'message' => 'Webhook executed successfully', 'data' => $postbody ];
        } );
    }
}

// Main loop
Loop::run( function () {
    $webhook = new Webhook();
    $resp    = $webhook->execute( $request );
    $output  = yield $resp;
    print_r( $resp ); // array with post body
} );
```